# ¿Descargar archivos en el navegador?

Tags: python, flask, backend, pytube

Estoy practicando con un código que descarga videos de YouTube

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os

def descargar_video(url, output_path):
    try: 
        yt = YouTube(url)
        
        print(f"Descargando video: {yt.title}...")
        yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(output_path=output_path)
        print(f"{yt.title} descargado exitosamente!!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"no se pudo descargar el video: {str(e)}")

def main(url):
    project_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    output_path = os.path.join(project_directory, 'descargas') #Directorio de descargas dentro del directorio del proyecto

    print(f"El directorio : {project_directory}")

    video = YouTube(url).title

    descargar_video(url, output_path)
    return video
```

Lo he juntado con un servidor de flask muy básico, la idea es que el usuario ponga la url en un formulario y entonces se descargue.

Pero solo soy capaz de descargar el video en una ruta dentro de mi proyecto. ¿Como puedo hacer que se descargue directamente en la carpeta de descargas de el ordenador?

Comment: pon la ruta donde quireres descargar en la variable `output_path`. En tu codigo estas descargando en project_path, pon otra ruta y lo descargará allá.